# using restsharp for oauth2 in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, rest, oauth-2.0, postman, restsharp

I'm new to oauth2, but I have tried my best to learn it.
this should be just a simple first step into getting token.

so the situation is like this.
I have succeeded trying it with postman web, but postman desktop always failed (callback timeout or Esockettimeout).
what I did was only filling in the type oauth2, granttype = client_credentials, client id = client_id and client secret = client_secret.
I dont know why, I have tried to view the console and making sure all parameter is the same. I have tried to disable my firewall and antivirus, and disable proxy and ssl on postman desktop's setting but still the same.

so I tried with powershell and iwr. using this :

```
iwr 'https://thesite.com/token?grant_type=client_credentials' -Headers @{ 'Authorization' = 'Basic OAuthE='} -Method "POST"
```

of course "thesite.com" should be my site, and "OAuthE=" was the authorization base64 from clientid:clientsecret.
this was successful in getting token.

I did it just to prove that my router and firewall setup is ok that the request and the token should be able to pass through.

so I tried to translate this to .net with newest restsharp (108.0.3).

```
    Dim client As RestClient
    client = New RestClient("https://thesite.com/token")
    client.Authenticator = New HttpBasicAuthenticator("clientid", "clientsecret")
    Dim Request = New RestRequest(Method.POST)

    Request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    Request.AddParameter("grant_type", "client_credentials")
    Dim response = client.Execute(Request)

    MsgBox(response.Content)
```

with this, response.content always empty, and response.statuscode always 0.

I have tried many other ways like putting the client id and client secret in request.addheader or request.addparameter. I even tried the executeasync, like :

```
        client.ExecuteAsync(Request, Sub(response)
                                     Console.Write(response.Content)
                                 End Sub)
```

but I'm not familiar with async, and have trouble getting it to not error. I want to get the response.content to a global variable to be use later, but I couldnt get it to not error, so the only way I can get it to run successfully only with console.write above, but it still return empty.

all the example or questions/answered about this seems to be simple only like that. But why mine always return empty ?

please help.
oh and please give me the answer and example in vb.net. All the other samples that I saw using c#, and I'm afraid that my trouble was because I translate it to vb.net wrong. And if can, I dont want to use async, only if it's really2 needed.

thx very much

Answer (score 0):

ok.
this is just for future reference if somebody encounter the same problem
so I have tried all things that I found (even tried the certificate and protocol of tls12, etc), and almost gave up.

when at last, I tried to change the addparameter for grant-type to :

```
            Request.AddQueryParameter("grant_type", "client_credentials", True)
```

at last I got the token after a week trying